# Problemas com belongs_to ao usar Ajax no Rails 4

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho três models em minha aplicação, `Order`, `Product` e `Items`. Dentro de `Items` tenho o seguinte código:

```ruby
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Tenho um formulário onde eu adiciono uma nova `Order`, depois sou redirecionado para a view 'show.html.erb', onde tenho um formulário em ajax para adicionar os itens, com campos para inserir os produtos referentes a estes itens, como a seguir:

```ruby
<%= form_for [@order, @order.items.build], remote: true do |f| %>
```

E uma listagem destes itens/produtos. É nessa listagem que estou tendo problemas:
Quero que minha lista tenha o seguinte código:

```ruby
    <% @order.items.each do |i| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= i.product.name %> </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Porém é lançado um erro de renderização, dizendo que o método `name` não existe para objeto nulo e, é preciso que eu atualize a página para funcionar. Mas, se eu alterar esta linha para isso \:

```ruby
<td><%= i.product_id %> </td>
```

A renderização é feita corretamente.

Tendo em vista este erro, creio que o problema esteja diretamente ligado ao retorno em json do meu objeto `@item`. Porém não faço idéia de como solucionar, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O erro só dá quando você adiciona um novo item por ajax? Se você atualiza a página funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode "burlar" o erro adicionando um `if i.product` a sua listagem:

```ruby
<td><%= i.product.name if i.product %></td>
```

Deixa de ocorrer o problema, porém não explica o porque. Isso já aconteceu comigo algumas vezes também.

Comment: Nesse caso você pode usar o método try: `i.product.try(:name)`

Comment: Galera Obrigado, resolveu meu problema, mas pq tenho que fazer isso? Qual o motivo dele não conseguir se "conectar" diretamente com o objeto em questão?

Comment: tenho a sensação de que vem um item nulo no retorno do ajax... consegue dar um console.log no retorno?

Answer (score 0):

Muito provavelmente o teu objeto tem um ID de um produto que já foi apagado.

Suponho que o seguinte também não funciona:

```ruby
<td><%= Product.find(i.product_id) %> </td>
```

Comment: Não funciona também, porém o product existe sim, se ele não existisse não iria funcionar ao atualizar a página. Ele não funciona na sequência da execução do ajax. Olha o erro que é gerado:
`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <% @order.items.each do |i| %>
    2: <tr>
    3:  <td><%= i.product.name %> </td>
    4:  <td></td>
    5: </tr>
    6: <% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema seja no seu *controller*.

Quando você da refresh, chama o show no *controller*, o `@ordem` é criado, aí todas as informações são carregadas. Após adicionar o item, você deve criar novamente a variável, ou o *rails* irá utilizar a informação do cache.

Outra coisa comum, é criar uma parcial _itens.js.erb para a lista, e você reenderiza ela novamente utilizando uma resposta format.js:

```js
$("#itens-index").html("<%= escape_javascript( render 'itens/itens' )%>");
```